# jQuery check if input field characters are highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

**Background**

I have a page that has 3 `input` elements which takes currency numbers

These `input` element of type `number` with jQuery handles which letting up to 2 decimal placing. If user tries to input 3rd decimal, it does not print which is great.

However...

**Issue**

When input already has valid 2d.p input such as `12.11` and wishes to highlight the field characters (such as click drag highlight to blue) to change/overwrite all, the jQuery handler think that its 3rd decimal input and does not print **BUT** what it actually needs to do is to overwrite the whole and start from the beginning.

**So**

Is there a way to check if the `input` field characters are highlighted?
I know that there is a way around this if my `input` has `type="text"` and just use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` BUT I want to keep it as `type="number"`.

Code: [jsfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/qtr30w05/)

**Any other suggestion to jQuery code handling 2 decimal place, I would appreciate**

Comment: Why did you check charcode? You're using input number. Is there particular reason?

Comment: @LaraBelle this project is base ASP.NET MVC5 and my model is decimal type which uses dynamic Html.EditorFor which create the matching input field which is type number. By using this, i know the input is restricted to number only, but to handle the decimal, dot.. I had to use keypress event which again captures any keypress so I need to handle that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, try the following minimal update to detect if the user has 'highlighted' the input value:

`if (CharAfterdot > 3 && !window.getSelection().toString()) { return false; }`

So if a 'selection' is found via the above method (not empty / undefined) the code allows further input (in your case overriding via highlight).

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qtr30w05/3/